# Find all objects that have duplicated values in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

How can I return all objects from a collection where `name` is same in all objects?

For example in this case `name: John`

```
[
 {
   _id: 1,
   name: "John",
   last: "Smith"
 },
 {
   _id: 8,
   name: "John",
   last: "Snow"
 },
 {
   _id: 16,
   name: "John",
   last: "McKay"
 },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use group in aggregate to return all data that have the same name

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "orig": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sizeOrig": {
        $size: "$orig"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      sizeOrig: {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$orig"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$orig"
    }
  }
])
```

example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/DfTA6_pUaRA

but if you want just single data for each duplication , you need just do it by group

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "orig": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hd1z77cdtp0

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "findAll({})" or just "find({})" with the collection name it will return an array object that will contain all the documents from the collection. For example if you have a collection or a model which is named "Employees" you need to do the following after connection to db.

```
Employees.find({});
```

This will return an array with all docs inside Employee collection. Once you have this returned you can iterate over it.